# Minification of Javascript and increasing performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refactoring

Here is my code for the html:

```
<div class="board">
  <table id="mastermind_table_one">
    <tr id="one">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>

  <table id="mastermind_table_two">
    <tr id="two">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="mastermind_table_three">
    <tr id="three">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is my code for the Javascript:

```
$('.next_round').click(function() {
  var count = 3;
  var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

  function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count === 0) {
      $('#mastermind_table_two').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td').each(function() {
          $(this).css("background-color", setRandomColor);
        })
      })
    clearInterval(counter);
  }
})
```

I am building a game in which when the "next_round" button is clicked, all the empty tds are filled with a random background color (there's more code, such as setRandomColor function, but it's not relevant to the question).

I have ten mastermind_tables total, and that is where the problem lies. I am repeating this code for each table. Does anyone know how I can have this listed just once and move to the next td when I click "next_round"?

i.e. the js code above is specific to mastermind_table_two. How can I have it be dynamic and move to the next td once the previous one is executed?

Comment: You could use the selector `[id^="mastermind_table_"]`, or, even better, give them classes if they're similar, and select by class :)

Comment: you end your `div` with `</board>`, you should fix this

Comment: Opps, sorry. I had a </div> but just posted it wrong. Thanks for correcting. I just tried this and it looks like it fills out all 10 rows at once. I was hoping to fill out just one row, then when you click "next_round", it fills out the next row, etc. Do you know if this is possible???

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

My mistake, must have readed your question in the worng way

Try this, its a bit of a hacky but might fit into your needs

```
 $('.next_round').click(function () {
        $('[id^=mastermind_table_]').each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("notTreated");//a fake class just to control
        });
        var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

        function timer() {
            var currenttable;
            if ((currenttable = $(".notTreated").first()) == null) {
                clearInterval(counter);
                return;
            }

            $(currenttable).find('td').each(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", setRandomColor);
            });
            //after treat this table, removes the fake class
            $(currenttable).removeClass("notTreated");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Silvio. I just tried this and it looks like it fills out all 10 rows at once. I was hoping to fill out just one row, then when you click "next_round", it fills out the next row, etc. Do you know if this is possible???

Comment: @user3007294 if u want to do 1 row per click, instead of setting intervar(timer, 1000), just call timer()